# Avoiding orphan typeable instances

Tags: haskell

It seems that data types promoted by `DataKinds` do not automatically get typeable instances. It is quite easy solve this by using `StandaloneDeriving` but this creates orphan instances. Is there anyway to avoid this?

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

module Orphan where

import Data.Typeable

deriving instance Typeable '[]
deriving instance Typeable '(:)
```

On compilation..

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Orphan           ( orphan.hs, interpreted )

orphan.hs:10:1: Warning: Orphan instance: instance Typeable '[]

orphan.hs:11:1: Warning: Orphan instance: instance Typeable (':)
Ok, modules loaded: Orphan.
*Orphan>
```

Comment: `-fno-warn-orphans`? Short of editing the ghc source code, your best bet is to submit a bug report. In fact, I think this is a bug, because `data A = A; deriving instance Typeable 'A; deriving instance Typeable A` gives you `typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy A) == typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy 'A)` = `True`, which is probably wrong.

Comment: Apparently this is fixed in GHC 7.10.

Comment: @user2407038 Presumably you started [this trac ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9858)? For future readers,  the `Typeable` bug doesn't look like it's going to get fixed for 7.10.

Comment: The ticket that automatically creates `Typeable` instances for promoted constructors in `base` is [#9111](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9111)